# Racket - creating a water density function with certain restrictions

Tags: scheme, racket

I am attempting to solve the following problem:

> Lately, Finn has been very curious about buckets of ice water and their properties. He has been reviewing the density of water and ice. It turns out the density of water in both states depends on many factors, including the temperature, atmospheric pressure, and the purity of the water.
>
> As an approximation, Finn has written the following function to determine the density of the water (or ice) in kg/m<sup>3</sup> as a function of temperature *t* in Celsius (−273.15 ≤ *t* ≤ 100):
>
> ```
> water-density(t) = ( 999.97 if t ≥ 0 ;
>                      916.7  if t < 0 )
> ```
>
> Write a function `water-density` that consumes an integer temperature `t` and produces either 999.97 or 916.7, depending on the value of `t`. However, you may only use the features of Racket given up to the end of Module 1.
>
> You may use `deﬁne` and mathematical functions, but **not** `cond`, `if`, lists, recursion, Booleans, or other things we’ll get to later in the course. Speciﬁcally, you may use any of the functions in section 1.5 of this page: http://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/beginner.html except for the following functions, which are **not** allowed: `sgn`, `ﬂoor`, `ceiling`, `round`.

This is what I have so far:

```
(define (water-density t)
  (+ (* (/ (min t 0) (min t -0.000001)) -83.27) 999.97))
```

This code does definitely work as long as the given temperature is not between -0.000001 and 0, but it will not work for temperatures between that range. What can I do to avoid this problem? Dividing by zero is the biggest problem I have here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We welcome programming questions, but this is not a homework-answering service. You are expected to understand the specific programming aspects posed by your homework, then ask questions about the programming stuff. Make it useful for other programmers, not just you or people doing your course.

Comment: What kind of course teaches people to program by limiting their options? all your questions "with certain restrictions/constraints" are pointless exercises, that's not how you'd write a program in real life!

Comment: I don't agree with the down-voting here. The OP has shown effort to try and find a solution, it's not his fault that the exercise makes no sense.

Comment: It would make for an interesting "bonus challenge" type of question, but it does come across as quite pointless.

Comment: Do you go to UWaterloo? Lol

Answer (score 3):

This is a somewhat.... interesting way of going about teaching programming, and I have a feeling this class is going to cause more StackOverflow questions to appear in the future, but you can do it by combining `max` and `min` to make a function that returns either 1 or 0 depending on whether its input is negative:

```
(define (negative->boolint n))
  (- 0
     (min 0
          (max (inexact->exact (floor n))
               -1))))
```

This function takes a number, rounds it down with `(inexact->exact (floor n))`, then the combination of `max` and `min` "bounds" the number to be between -1 and 0, then subtracts that result from 1. Since after conversion to an integer the number can never be between -1 and 0, the bounding just results in 0 for positives and zero and -1 negatives. The subtraction part means the function returns `(- 0 0)` for all positive numbers and zero and returns `(- 1 -1)` for all negative numbers. By combining the result of this function with some arithmetic, you can get the behavior you want:

```
(define (water-density t)
  (- 999.97
     (* 83.27
        (negative->boolint t))))
```

If `t` is positive or zero, then the result of `(* 83.27 (negative->boolint t))` will just be zero. Otherwise, the difference of the two densities will be subtracted, giving you the correct result.

This works because it's just taking advantage of `max` and `min`'s built-in conditional functionality to do conditional arithmetic. You could probably achieve the same with some level of hackery for `round` or `abs` or other statements that have conditional logic.

#### EDIT

My apologies, I missed the part of your question about not being able to use the rounding functions. Want you want is still doable however, by using two base functions for simulating conditionals: `abs` and `expt`. Getting conditionals from `abs` is fairly straightforward, you can divide a number by its absolute value to get it's sign. The reason you need `expt` is because it lets you get around the division by zero issue with `abs`, because `(expt 0 x)` is 0 for all positive numbers, 1 for zero, and undefined for negative numbers. We can use this to make a `zero->boolint` function:

```
(define (zero->boolint x)
  (expt 0 (abs x)))
```

With this, we can add its result to the numerator and denominator to get around division by zero in `(/ x (abs x))`. Since this causes the division by zero case to return 1, we now have a `nonnegative->boolint` function:

```
(define (nonnegative->boolint x)
  (/ (+ 1
        (/ (+ (zero->boolint x) x)
           (+ (zero->boolint x) (abs x))))
     2))
```

The inner division takes care of dividing a number by its absolute value to return -1 for negatives and 1 for positives and zero. The outer addition by 1 and then division by 2 turns this into 0 for negatives and 1 for positives and zero. In order to get a `negative->boolint` function, we just need some sort of `not` operation - which in the case of 1 for `true` and 0 for `false` is just subtracting the value from 1. So we can define `negative->boolint` based on only the conditional logic of `abs` and `expt` as:

```
(define (negative->boolint x)
  (- 1 (nonnegative->boolint x))
```

This works as expected with the definition of `water-density`. Also, please don't ever do this in real world code. No matter how "clever" it may seem at the time.

Comment: This is a clever solution, but unfortunately, OP mentioned that `floor` isn't allowed. I tried myself to come up with a working solution and got nowhere.

Comment: Oh! My apologies for the misread. That is... even more unusual a question then. I'll see what I can come up with then edit to fix.

Comment: Managed to figure out a solution. Abusing `expt` like that is something I hope I never, ever, ever have to write in code again.